# Flask large app - Import functions from utils file

Tags: python, flask

I need help with import fuctions from utils file in my Flask app.

```
# Structure of my app: 
**(updated)**

apps
-[admin]
--forms_admin.py
--views_admin.py
--models_admin.py
-[user]
--forms_user.py
--views_user.py
--models_user.py
-[dashboard]
-__init__.py (empty)
...
...
-utils.py
```

utils file

```
# utils.py

def select_role()
    ...
    return roles_list

def required_roles(*roles):
    def decorator(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
            if not str(current_user.role_id) in roles:
                abort(403)
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return decorated_function
    return decorator
```

I need import function `def select_role()` from `forms_user.py`.

But when i trying:

```
# forms_user.py

from apps.utils import select_role
```

In terminal shell is error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'select_role'`

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

What is best practice for import functions from utils file?

Thanks for any answer.

Comment: does yout app has __init__.py

Comment: hm, yes i have __init__.py  but is only empty file like in Flask-Cookiecutter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, make sure that you have an `__init__.py` file in your apps directory even empty, this will tell python that app is a module and you can import from it.

in you  forms_user.py you can do a relative import

```
from utils import select_role
```

Comment: I have init.py in app folder (and i updated structure in my question). And when i try your import, in terminal is still error:     from ..utils import select_district, select_role
:/

Comment: And 2nd information: in forms_user.py have 
    'import from apps.user.models_user import User, Role' 
and this import works probably fine (is on first line and shell is terminated only on problematic import)

Comment: its a specific problem because in my utils on begin of file i have import 
'from apps.admin.models_admin import PromoProduct'

If i remove this import, all works fine.
Espoir thank you for your effort.